# LCD displaying random series of letters instead of one on Arduino. Suspecting something wrong with the mapping function

Tags: arduino

I have a potentiometer connected to pin 6.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

int letterNum;
int letter;


void setup()
{
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
    pinMode(6,INPUT);

}

void loop()
{     
    letterNum = map(analogRead(6),0,1023,1,26)+96;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.write(letterNum);
 }
```

When I have the potentiometer at 0, the result should be just the letter a. Instead, it just goes through a random series of letters and will not stop. This seems to happen in any position. Please help!

Comment: your code looks ok to me. looks I'd suspect an electronics problem. check the common ground. you should probably add a delay in your loop to avoid overflowing the displays input buffer but that's not related to your problem

Comment: I added the delay, but as you said it was unrelated. I'm also doing it on tinkercad.com so maybe the website just has an issue with mapping? Thanks for the advice though!